# Grammar and verb use in a sentence

Tags: verbs

I was texted this message:

わたしのニックネームはさとなので、さとって呼んでください

I'm guessing it means "my nickname is Sato, please call me Sato" but I don't understand the grammar. What's "なので"? How does one use the verb 呼んで, why is there a って before？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how much you know so I hope this isn't too patronising.

> わたしのニックネームはさとなので ...
> My nickname is Sato so ...

The base sentence here is X = わたしのニックネームはさとです.

Xので means 'because X ...' or 'X, so ...'. But you can't attach ので to directly to です. Normally, conjunctions attach to the informal form (that would be です --> だ),  but we never say だので either. The だ changes to な (probably for good reasons I don't understand) to give AはBなのでC = "A is B so C".

> さと**って**呼{よ}んでください
> please call me Sato

In this sentence って is just a casual form of the quotation particle と: the particle that is used with verbs like いう and おもう among others.

I find it helps to think of this particle meaning 'as', especially if it also takes an object:

> XをYと呼{よ}ぶ
> Call X (as) Y

e.g. 犬{いぬ}をわんちゃんと呼{よ}ぶ = "Call the dog (as) Wanchan".

Beware though that in other contexts って can be a casual form of は or of the whole という. Context and experience will tell you which is which.